# Indexed values with neo4j

Tags: database, indexing, neo4j, similarity

We're using Neo4j for a data management system. However we are building a record matching module which needs some high speed lookup inverted indexes as described in this paper:

http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV87Christen.pdf

Should I be using a different database for these indexes?

Thanks

Comment: Please add a lot more detail. What kind of record matching module? Do you want to build these indexes per the research, or what?  It's unlikely that question answerers will read the academic paper to try to understand what you're looking for.  Why are you using neo4j right now?  What have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps also a summary of the paper as you can't expect people to read it.